# Do methods on Immutable.js Records replicate?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

My app loads about 30-50 instances of an `Immutable.js Record`. I'd like to write a `getter` that applies a few operations to the data before returning it.

Is this efficient? Or will I end up with 30-50 copies in-memory of any method I write?

eta:

This is my current pattern:

```
export const EntityRecord = Immutable.Record({
  // key/values
})

class Entity extends EntityRecord {

  getProp() {
    return this.get('property')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation.  You could simply write a utility method

```
export function myRecordGetter(myRecord) {
   ... do your work here ....
   return thingYouComputed;
}
```

Then just import and call it.  If you plan to "extend" the functionality of a record, it depends on how you do it.

Comment: thanks @rooftop. i added a snippet to OP.  do you know if creating a `static` method on `Entity` would be as effective as creating a dedicated utility function?  (this might be a simple question--i've never done true `oop`)